# Magento2: Unable to transfer/move the CSV file from var/report to another server

Tags: magento2, csv, server-setup, magento2.4.5

I'm unable to move the generated csv file from my var/report folder to another sftp server.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Access the CSV file from the var/report directory then move to pub/ .

Now, you should be able to access the CSV file from anywhere within your server using the path http://your_domain/pub/file.csv or http://your_ip_address/pub/file.csv, depending on your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps, you can follow to move the var/report/filename to another server:

**Step1:** Create below constructor to the particular class.

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Ftp $ftpConnection
){
    $this->ftpConnection = $ftpConnection;
}
```

**Step2:** Create a function & add below code:

```
$open = $this->ftpConnection->open(
    array(
        'host' => 'hostname',
        'user' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'ssl' => true,
        'passive' => true
    )
);

if ($open) {
    $fileName = 'report-filename'; // fetch the file name that you want to move
    $content = file_get_contents(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR . '/report' . $fileName);
    $this->ftpConnection->cd("--another server directory path--");
    $this->ftpConnection->write(self::FILE_NAME_ON_FTP, $content);
    $this->ftpConnection->close();
}
```

This will help you to move files from current server to another server.

**Note:** You can implement the above code to the CRON/controller/event/plugin or existing function to trigger it.